# move content section partially on top of nav bar

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I try to move my content section partially on top of my nav bar. Before I added the css code. My content section look fine.

After I add three lines of code in my CSS, my content-section did move little over the nav bar, but my content section's right margin is gone. And content section no longer centered. Please help me to fix this.

Here is my original code:

```css
.content-section {
  /* 10 px on top with nav bar */
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 9999;
 
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5 px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: lime !important;
    }
    
    .content-section {
      /* 10 px on top with nav bar */
      /*
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -30px;
    z-index: 9999;
    */
      padding: 0 10px;
      background: white;
      border-color: black;
      border-width: 5 px;
      border-style: solid;
    }
    
    .import-notes {
      background: yellow;
      /* add code to make in full width */
      margin-left: -10px;
      margin-right: -10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="content-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test this is a test. This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This
        is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is
        a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test
        this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.</p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p>(4)This is a test </p>
      <p>(5)This is a test </p>
      <p>(6)This is a test </p>
      <p>(7)This is a test </p>
      <p>(8)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share you complete html and css for the elemnts in play

Comment: If you can create a funtional snippet

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "on top of navbar" and what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: bootstrap 3, I would like to move my content section little overlap with navbar.

Comment: I just post my complete html and css code.

Comment: "little overlap with navbar" could be interpreted in at least 4 different ways...

Comment: move content section up vertically.

Comment: The navbar overlap has already been done in the code CK8 posted. So I'm pretty sure the question is really just asking how to get the margin on the right side of the content box back to the same margin we see on the left of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `position: absolute` to `position: relative` on the `.content-section` class

```css
.content-section {
  /* 10 px on top with nav bar */
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -30px;
  z-index: 9999;
 
  padding: 0 10px;
  background: white;
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 5 px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background: lime !important;
    }
    
    .content-section {
      /* 10 px on top with nav bar */
      /*
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -30px;
    z-index: 9999;
    */
      padding: 0 10px;
      background: white;
      border-color: black;
      border-width: 5 px;
      border-style: solid;
    }
    
    .import-notes {
      background: yellow;
      /* add code to make in full width */
      margin-left: -10px;
      margin-right: -10px;
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="content-section">
      <p>(1)This is a test this is a test. This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This
        is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is
        a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test
        this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.</p>
      <p>(2)This is a test </p>
      <p>(3)This is a test </p>
      <p>(4)This is a test </p>
      <p>(5)This is a test </p>
      <p>(6)This is a test </p>
      <p>(7)This is a test </p>
      <p>(8)This is a test </p>
      <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you want or not, due to the ambiguity in your question. With this code, the jump to the left has been fixed, but there is still room to see the green background.

```css
.container {
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    margin-left:0 !important;
    margin-right:0 !important;
}

.content-section { 
    /* 10 px on top with nav bar */
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -30px;
    z-index: 9999;
    
    padding:0 10px;
    background : white;
    border: 5px solid black;
}
.import-notes { 
    background : yellow;       
   /* add code to make in full width */
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -10px;
}
body { background: lime !important; }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">XYZ123</a>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content-section">
            <p>(1)This is a test this is a test. This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.This is a test this is a test.</p>
            <p>(2)This is a test </p>
            <p>(3)This is a test </p>
            <p>(4)This is a test </p>
            <p>(5)This is a test </p>
            <p>(6)This is a test </p>
            <p>(7)This is a test </p>
            <p>(8)This is a test </p>
            <p class="import-notes">This is full width no padding</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

At first, in the `.container` section, I just used `margin-left:0;` and `margin-right:0;`. When this didn't work, I "Inspect Elemented" and discovered the specificity in the Bootstrap is what is keeping the properties from changing. The original value for the `margin-left` and `right` properties was `auto`. I added **`!important`** to override this, but you should know this is bad practice.